# can't move grid to the center of page using flexbox

Tags: javascript, grid

how can i move grid to the center of the page? I managed to move it horizontaly to the center using display:grid on grid div but i cant move it vertically. please explain why this is the case, also why flexbox justify-content is not working as well

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  let row = document.createElement('div');
  row.className = 'row';
  for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
    let box = document.createElement('div');
    box.className = 'box';
    row.appendChild(box);
  }
  document.getElementById('grid').appendChild(row);
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  border: black 1px solid;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.row {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <h1>Etch-a-Sketch</h1>
      <div id="grid"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The grid and title are at the center of the container, but the container is only as large as the content. You should explicitly specify with CSS that you want the container to be as large as the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `body` `min-height` to `100vh` to take the full-screen height, and the `#container` element height to `100%` to take the full `body` height.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  let row = document.createElement('div');
  row.className = 'row';
  for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
    let box = document.createElement('div');
    box.className = 'box';
    row.appendChild(box);
  }
  document.getElementById('grid').appendChild(row);
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  border: black 1px solid;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.row {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <h1>Etch-a-Sketch</h1>
      <div id="grid"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```